# How to call a class's method in python?

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm new to python and trying to write a python script that would take two command line arguments, do something to them, and return the output back to the stdout.

My script is like this:

```
class MyClass:
  def GET(self):
    #get the passed in arguments in arg1 and arg2
    return self.perform(arg1, arg2)

  def perform(self, arg1, arg2):
    return arg1+arg2

if __name__ == "__main__":
   #call the GET method of MyClass with all the arguments
```

- How can I pass the command line arguments `sys.argv[1:]` to `GET` method of `MyClass`?
- Will the signature of `GET` change from `GET(self)` to `GET(self, arg1, arg2)`?

Comment: It seems like you already have the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've written there is instance methods, which need an instance for you to call them on.
E.g.

```
x = MyClass() # create an instance of MyClass
x.GET()
```

However, `arg1` and `arg2` are never initialised, so your `GET` method won't know what they are. If you want to pass them into `GET` you would need to specify them as parameters:

```
class MyClass:
  def GET(self, arg1, arg2):
    ...
```

and then you could call the method with

```
x.GET(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

but that would make `GET` kind of pointless, since all it does is redirect the call to the `perform` method.

If you prefer, you could pass the `argv` array itself to `GET`. That would require:

```
class MyClass:
  def GET(self, args):
     return self.perform(args[1], args[2])
  ...

x = MyClass()
x.GET(sys.argv)
```

If you want to output the result to `stdout`, you would use `print`. E.g.

```
print(x.GET(sys.argv))
```